# expected life absorbing Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

No idea on how to start this question. Any help would be much appreciated.

A ﬂea lives on a polyhedron with N vertices, labelled $1, . . . , N$. It hops from vertex to
vertex in the following manner: if one day it is on vertex $i > 1$, the next day it hops to one
of the vertices labelled $1, . . . , i−1$ with equal probability, and it dies upon reaching vertex $1$. Let $X_n$ be the position of the ﬂea on day $n$. Show that the expected life of the flea is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{i}$$

Comment: Are you assuming that initially the flea is on any of the vertices with equal probability? Or is it initially on vertex N? Which of these is assumed makes the answer different. [Also you should put the 1 in the phrase "it dies upon reaching vertex 1". At present that sentence ends with the word vertex.]

Answer (score 1):

**Added reference:** This problem is discussed in Sheldon M. Ross's *Introduction to Probability Models* in section 4.5.2. "A Model for Algorithmic Efficiency".

---

For $i>1$ define $f_i(x)$ as the expected amount of time spent in state $i$, 
starting at $x$, i.e., 
$$f_i(x)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{[X_n=i]}\,\bigg|\, X_0=x\right).$$

Since the flea can visit any state $i>1$ at most once, and state 1 is absorbing, 
$f_i$ is the unique function with $f_i(i)=1$, $f_i(1)=0$, and is 
otherwise *harmonic*, that is, 
$$f_i(x) = \begin{cases} 0   & 1=x \\[5pt]
                         1   & \, i=x\\[5pt]
                        \sum_y p(x,y) f_i(y) & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Solving the equation above for this particular Markov chain gives
$$f_i(x) = \begin{cases} 0   & 1\leq x<i \\
                     1   & i=x\\
                     1/i & i<x \end{cases}$$

The flea's average lifetime is therefore 
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{[X_n>1]}\,\bigg|\, X_0=N\right)=\sum_{i>1} f_i(N) = {1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+\cdots+{1\over N-1}+1+0+0+\cdots.$$

Answer (score 0):

From what I found I must assume the flea is initially on vertex $N$, in order that the expected lifetime comes out $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac1i.$
For each $k$ between $1$ and $N$ let $e(k)$ be the expected life of the flea, given it starts at vertex $k$. Then clearly we want $e(1)=0$ (immediate death, expected lifetime $0$), while also $e(2)=1$ since the flea gets only the one jump to death at vertex $1$. In general, suppose the flea is presently on vertex $k>1$. Then he gets with certainty his first jump, so that $e(k)=1+...$. His next jump being to one of the previous $k-1$ vertices with equal probability, we can see the relation
$$e(k)=1+[e(1)+e(2)+\cdots +e(k-1)]/(k-1). \tag{1}$$
This gives the $e(k)$ recursively, and we find e.g. $e(3)=3/2,\ e(4)=11/6,\ e(5)=25/12.$
It so happens that these fractions match the results of summing the first $k-1$ reciprocals of natural numbers $1/1+1/2+\cdots+1/(k-1).$

So "all that's left" is to show that, provided we *define* the $e(k)$ by these reciprocal sums, then the $e(k)$ also satisfy the initial $e(1)=0$ [this works since an empty sum is $0$ by definition] as well as the recurrence equation $(1)$. I have filled some pages trying to do that with no immediate success, and have also tried to do it with generating functions, using the taylor expansion of $g(x)=-x \ln(1-x)/(1-x)$ whose coefficient of $x^n$ is the sum of the first $n-1$ terms of the harmonic series, but no luck so far.

**Proof of recursion formula**
As suggested, define $s(k)=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac1j .$ It will be more convenient to state the recursion formula as
$$s(n+1)=1+\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n s(k).$$ Substituting for $s(k)$ here the above formula gives the following double sum for $s(n+1):$
$$s(n+1)=1+\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac1j .$$ 
The key now is to reverse the order of summation. The restrictions imposed by the sum are that $1 \le j < k \le n$, and to reverse, we may take first $j$ going from $1$ to $n-1$, and then for any fixed $j$ the index $k$ ranges from $j+1$ to $n$. This means the re-written $s(n+1)$ becomes
$$s(n+1)=1+\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \frac1j .$$ 
Now the fraction $\frac1j$ is constant in the inner sum, where it appears $n-j$ times. So its contribution is $\frac{n-j}{j}=\frac nj -1.$ Thus the inner sum has been evaluated and we now have the single sum
$$s(n+1)=1+\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}[n/j-1].$$
Only a little algebra now brings this into the form $s(n+1)=1+1/2+\cdots +1/n$, completing the inductive proof that the defined formulas $s(n)$ in terms of the partial harmonic sums must agree with the values of $s(n)$ viewed as expected life spans of the flea if it starts at the vertex $n$ (see above for this part).