# Expected value: Random sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, expectation, random

Let $R$ be a random number generator such that R(n) returns an integer in the range  $0,1,...,n−1$ with uniform probability. Note that this is not a true function in the mathematical sense, as in- putting the same number a second time will not necessarily yield the same result. The random number generator only works for $n>1$.
Starting from a googol, ie $x_0 = 10^{100}$, consider the sequence $x_i = R(x_i−1)$. Eventually the sequence terminates when $x_s = 0$ for some $s$ and no further generation is possible. **What is E[s]**

Comment: Misread the question...the range can never increase, and (probably) decreases on each round.  Yes?

Comment: There's a simple recursion...Starting with $k$ the first trial either ends the game (prob. $\frac 1k$) or we start up again with, possibly, a smaller range.  Specifically $E_k=\frac 1k+\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^k(E_i+1)$.  Easy to implement (though maybe not up to a google).

Comment: Threw together some code for the recursion.  Might have messed it up.  Assuming I got it right, the sequence doesn't look promising.

Comment: You need one step, and then the rest: $E_k=1+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}E_i$ with $E_0=0$

Comment: (which gives a very famous series)

Comment: Presumably there's a typo in the OP, which should say "works only for $n \color{blue}{\ge} 1$."

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471161/expected-life-absorbing-markov-chain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to see that the expected value is the ${x_0}^\text{th}$ [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and we also find a recursion for the variance.

For $n\ge 1$, let $S(n)$ denote the (random) number of steps the procedure requires to reach $0$ when started with $x_0=n$. Then
$$\begin{align}S(n)&= 1 + S(U_{0,n-1})\\
&= 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i)
\end{align}
$$
where $U_{0,n-1}$ is a random variable uniformly distributed on $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ and $[...]$ are Iverson (indicator) brackets.

**Expected Value**

From the preceding equation, noting that $[U_{0,n-1}=i]$ and $S(i)$ are mutually independent, it follows that
$$\begin{align}
E(S(n))&=1+E(S(U_{0,n-1}))\\
&=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}P(U_{0,n-1}=i)\,E(S(i))\\
&=1 + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}E(S(i)).
\end{align}
$$
Thus, letting $m_n=E(S(n))$,
$$\begin{align}m_0&=0\\
m_n &= 1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m_i,\quad n\ge 1\tag{1}\\
\end{align}
$$
which is a defining recursion for the [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Identities_involving_harmonic_numbers); i.e., 
$$m_n = H_n,\quad n\ge 1.$$

That is, (1) implies that $m_n$ also satisfies the standard defining recursion for the Harmonic numbers: 
$$m_n = m_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}.\tag{2}$$

To see this, note that from (1) we have
$$\begin{align}m_n-m_{n-1}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m_i - \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}m_i\\
&= \frac{1}{n}m_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}m_i - \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}m_i\\
&= \frac{1}{n}m_{n-1} + (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1})\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}m_i\\
&= \frac{1}{n}m_{n-1} + (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1})(n-1)(m_{n-1}-1)\tag{3}\\
&= m_{n-1}(\frac{1}{n}+(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1})(n-1)) - (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1})(n-1)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
$$
where in line (3) we have used (1) in the form $n(m_n-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}m_i$ with $n\leftarrow n-1$.

**Numerical value of $H_{10^{100}}$**

[Computations suggest](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) that the number of decimal digits in the numerator (and likewise in the denominator) of $H_{10^n}$ is approximately $10^n\,\log_{10}\,e$. This would imply that displaying both the numerator and denominator of $H_{10^{100}}$ as decimal numerals would require a total of approximately $0.84\,10^{100}$ decimal digits --  quite infeasible, as it far exceeds the number of atoms in the known universe.

However, there are various bounding results that will give a good approximation; e.g. this one (R. High, "Asymptotics of the harmonic sum", *Amer. Math. Monthly* 99 (1992), no. 7, 684–685):

$$H_n = \log\,n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2\,n} - \frac{1}{12\,n^2} + \epsilon_n,\quad 0<\epsilon_n<\frac{1}{120\,n^4}.
$$

This gives more than $400$ decimal digits of $H_{10^{100}}$, the first few of which are 
$$230.835724964306101262405657558518823191152308198817221202138557$$

---

**Variance**

Similarly, the variance of $S(n)$ can be found as follows:
$$\begin{align}V(S(n)) &= V(S(U_{0,n-1}))\\
&= V(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i))\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}V([U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i)) + 2\sum_{0\le i<j\le n-1}\mathrm{cov}([U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i),\,[U_{0,n-1}=j]\,S(j))\\
\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}V([U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i))&=E([U_{0,n-1}=i]^2\,S(i)^2) - (E([U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i)))^2\\
&= \frac{1}{n}E(S(i)^2) - (\frac{1}{n}E(S(i)))^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n}(V(S(i)) + (E(S(i)))^2) - \frac{1}{n^2}(E(S(i)))^2\\
&= \frac{1}{n}V(S(i)) + \frac{1}{n}{H_i}^2 - \frac{1}{n^2}{H_i}^2\\
&= \frac{1}{n}V(S(i)) + \frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n}){H_i}^2\\
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}&\mathrm{cov}([U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i),\,[U_{0,n-1}=j]\,S(j))\\
&=E([U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i)\,[U_{0,n-1}=j]\,S(j))-E([U_{0,n-1}=i]\,S(i))\,E([U_{0,n-1}=j]\,S(j))\\
&= 0 - \frac{1}{n}H_i\,\frac{1}{n}H_j\\
&= -\frac{1}{n^2}H_i\,H_j.
\end{align}$$

Hence
$$\begin{align}V(S(n)) &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}V(S(i)) + \frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n})\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{H_i}^2 - \frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{0\le i<j\le n-1}H_i H_j\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}V(S(i)) + 1-\frac{1}{n}H_n.
\end{align}$$

**NB**: The last line was obtained by using SageMath and OEIS to reveal the following surprising identity:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{H_i}^2 - \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{0\le i,j\le n-1}H_i H_j = 1 - \frac{1}{n}H_n.
$$

Thus, letting $v_n$ denote $V(S(n))$, we have the following recursion:
$$\begin{align}v_1 &= 0\\
v_n &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}v_i + 1 - \frac{1}{n}H_n,\quad n\ge 2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. How does one solve this to get a numerical value? In the question the starting value is a googol, $10^{100}$

Comment: @FernandoAlonso - I added some remarks about the numerical value.

Comment: For a proof of the noted Harmonic Numbers identity, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944450/16397

Answer (score 0):

One can frame the problem as a tower of states, where one can transition to lower states until reaching zero. Note that this is a Markov process, since the probability of reaching a given integer only depends on the previous state (the previous maximum integer $x$). Let $p_n(x|y)$ denote the transition probability of going from $y$ to $x$ in $n$ steps. From an integer $y$ we can only go downwards, e.g., to $x<y$. The mean of $n$ steps required to go from $x_0$ to 0 is thus

\begin{equation}
E(n,x_0)=\sum_{i=1}^{x_0} \, i \, p_i(0|x_0) 
\end{equation}

Note that $p_1(y|x)=1/x$, $\forall y<x$, since we have the same probability to go to any of the integers between 0 and $x$. Also, descending from an integer $x$ in $x$ steps implies perform $x$ decays to the immediately inferior state, i.e., $p_x(0|x)=\prod_y^x p_1(y-1|y)$.

We can proceed in an inductive approach, starting from small initial integers.

- Firstly, for $x_0=1$, $p_1(0|1)=1$, and hence $E(n,1)=p_1(0|1)=1$.
- For $x_0=2$, we have to consider $p_1(0|2)=1/2$ and $p_2(0|2)=p_1(0|1)p_1(1|2)=1 \times 1/2$. Thus, $E(n,2)=p_1(0|2) + 2 p_2(0|2)=1/2 + 2\times 1/2=1 + 1/2$.
- For $x_0=3$, $E(n,3)=p_1(0|3) + 2 p_2(0|3) + 3 p_3(0|3)$. We have $p_3(0|3)=p_1(2|3)p_1(1|2)p_1(0|1)=(1/3)\times(1/2)\times 1$. On the other hand, to reach 0 in 2 steps, we have two possibilities, and hence we sum over both possible paths: $p_2(0|3)=p_1(2|3)p_1(0|2) + p_1(1|3)p_1(0|1)=1/3 \times (1 + 1/2)$. Therefore, $E(n,3)=1 + 1/2 + 1/3$.

We can already see the trend

\begin{equation}
E(n,x)=\sum_{k=1}^x \frac{1}{k} = H_x,
\end{equation}

where $H_x$ is the $x^{th}$ harmonic number. Since asymptotically, $H_x \sim \ln(x) + \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, for a googol $x=10^{100}$ we get $E(n,10^{100})=H_{10^{100}} \sim 230$.